# Can MongoDB be a consistent event store?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, event-sourcing, consistency

When storing events in an event store, the order in which the events are stored is very important especially when projecting the events later to restore an entities current state.

MongoDB seems to be a good choice for persisting the event store, given its speed and flexibel schema (and it is often recommended as such) but there is no such thing as a transaction in MongoDB meaning the correct event order can not be garanteed.

Given that fact, should you not use MongoDB if you are looking for a consistent event store but rather stick with a conventional RDMS, or is there a way around this problem?

Comment: how would transactions guarantee event order?  If you timestamp each event would _that_ not guarantee order?

Comment: Have you read up on [Atomic Operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) in MongoDB?  If you are `$push`ing events onto an array for example, you should have a consistent order.  If your events are ephemeral you could also consider using a [Capped Collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) which maintains documents in insertion order, with a FIFO auto age-out. Another option is to consider [sequences](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers).  Would be helpful to explain how you are modelling the events.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the term "event store" as you are using it, but I can address some of the issues in your question.  I believe it is probably reasonable to use MongoDB for what you want, with a little bit of care.

In MongoDB, each document has an `_id` field which is by default in `ObjectId` format, which consists of a server identifier, and then a timestamp and then a sequence counter.  So you can sort on that field and you'll get your objects in their creation order, provided the `ObjectId`s are all created on the same machine.

Most MongoDB client drivers create the `_id` field locally before sending an insert command to the database.  So if you have multiple clients connecting to the database, sorting by `_id` won't do what you want since it will sort first by server-hash, which is not what you want.

But if you can convince your MongoDB client driver to not include the `_id` in the insert command, then the server will generate the ObjectId for each document and they will have the properties you want.  Doing this will depend on what language you're working in since each language has its own client driver.  Read the driver docs carefully or dive into their source code -- they're all open source.  Most drivers also include a way to send a raw command to the server.  So if you construct an `insert` command by hand this will certainly allow you to do what you want.

This will break down if your system is so massive that a single database server can't handle all of your write traffic.  The MongoDB solution to needing to write thousands of records per second is to set up a sharded database.  In this case the ObjectIds will again be created by different machines and won't have the nice sorting property you want.  If you're concerned about outgrowing a single server for writes, you should look to another technology that provides distributed sequence numbers.